# Get daily stock portfolio from incomplete transaction time series in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to come up with an SQL solution for the following problem. I have a table in which stock transactions are saved. As transactions don't occur on a daily basis the time series in the table is incomplete.

Table TRANSACTION

| Date | Depot | Ticker | Buy or Sell | Shares |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | A | MSFT | BUY | 100 |
| 2022-02-04 | B | AAPL | BUY | 20 |
| 2022-02-05 | A | MSFT | SELL | 80 |
| 2022-02-07 | A | PG | BUY | 50 |
| 2022-02-08 | A | PG | BUY | 30 |
| 2022-02-08 | A | PG | BUY | 20 |
| 2022-02-09 | A | PG | BUY | 50 |
| 2022-02-10 | B | T | BUY | 10 |

Now I would like to write a SQL statement that gives me the daily share count per depot an ticker for every day since 2022-02-01. The expected result would be this.

| Date | Depot | Ticker | Share Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | A | MSFT | 100 |
| 2022-02-02 | A | MSFT | 100 |
| 2022-02-03 | A | MSFT | 100 |
| 2022-02-04 | A | MSFT | 100 |
| 2022-02-04 | B | AAPL | 20 |
| 2022-02-05 | A | MSFT | 20 |
| 2022-02-05 | B | AAPL | 20 |
| 2022-02-06 | A | MSFT | 20 |
| 2022-02-06 | B | AAPL | 20 |
| 2022-02-07 | A | MSFT | 20 |
| 2022-02-07 | A | PG | 50 |
| 2022-02-07 | B | AAPL | 20 |
| 2022-02-08 | A | PG | 50 |
| 2022-02-08 | A | MSFT | 20 |
| 2022-02-08 | A | PG | 100 |
| 2022-02-08 | B | AAPL | 50 |
| 2022-02-09 | A | MSFT | 20 |
| 2022-02-09 | A | PG | 150 |
| 2022-02-09 | B | AAPL | 50 |
| 2022-02-10 | A | MSFT | 20 |
| 2022-02-10 | A | PG | 150 |
| 2022-02-10 | B | AAPL | 50 |
| 2022-02-10 | B | T | 10 |

What I'v done so far:

- A: Getting a list of all dates between 2022-02-01 and the current date (e.g. 2022-02-10).
- B: Getting a running total over the shares column by depot and ticker ordered by date.
- A Left join B

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(date) AS (
  VALUES('2022-02-01')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(date, '+1 day')
  FROM dates
  WHERE date < DATE()
)
SELECT dt.Date
    , tr.Date
    , tr.Ticker
    , tr.Shares AS [Share Count]
FROM dates dt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Date
        , Depot
        , Ticker
        , SUM(shares) OVER (PARTITION BY Depot, Ticker ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Shares
    FROM TRANSACTION
    ORDER BY Depot, Date, Ticker
) ON (
    tr.Date <= dt.Date
)
ORDER BY dt.Date, Ticker
```

That doesn't seem to do the trick as the running total does not properly aggregate the date rows. The result looks more like a kind of cross join between the synthetic date table and the transaction table.

Where am I wrong? Has anyone a solution for my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, just expanded on your idea.
I have hard-coded end date in below example, but that can be changed as per requirement.

The dates CTE is just building dates within the needed range.
In the next sub-query (t1), there are two more columns added - column md for max date and column s_shares to get a running sum of shares based on if share is bought (added) or subtracted if sold.

We then select from the two sets values between dates max date (column md) and original date.

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(date1) AS (
  select date('2022-02-01')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  date(date1, '+1 day')
  FROM dates
  WHERE date1 <  date('2022-02-10')
) select d.date1,depot,ticker, s_shares 
from dates d, 
(select date1, 
case 
coalesce(lead(date1) over (partition by depot, ticker order by date1),0) 
when 0 then date('2022-02-10', '+1 day')
else lead(date1) over (partition by depot, ticker order by date1) 
end md,
depot, ticker, buyorsell,
sum(case when buyorsell = 'SELL' then -(Shares) else Shares end) 
over (partition by depot, ticker order by Date1 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) s_shares
from tic) t1
where d.date1< t1.md
and d.date1>= t1.date1
order by depot, ticker, d.date1;
```

Refer to the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=15b2b5ef4573eab0f23fbe4c7721a4c7).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Result looks much better now. I found another interesting side effect, though. If a stock has >1 transactions a day the share count will be split from this day on as if those transactions would have bought different stocks. I adjusted the input data again for PG to showcase.

Comment: Are you looking to see all entries (even within a day) or just total for a day ("daily stock portfolio)? The present solution, gives total for the day. Let me know if you need to see all entries and I will check that.

Comment: I'm interested in the total for a day and your last update did the trick. Everything seems fine now. Many thanks for your help and sorry for the multiple iterations!

Comment: np, feel free to upvote answer.

Comment: I'm still lacking the reputation for upvoting. But I'll make up for it as soon as I can.